# C# Access to the path is denied... Client.Download(filelink, path)

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, webclient, directory-permissions

I've a problem with my code:
when I try to download a file from dropbox, and put it in my Roaming folder something goes wrong, here's the error Log:

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. --->              System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path'C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\.maycraft' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at MayCraftLauncher.Program.downloadExist() in c:\Users\Marco\Desktop\MayCraftLauncher\C# SourceCode\MayCraftLauncher\MayCraftLauncher\Program.cs:line 71
```

Obviously I tried to run Visual Studio with administator rights, but nothing...

And here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace MayCraftLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        
        public static System.Threading.Thread existDownloading = new System.Threading.Thread(downloadExist);

        public static string userName = Environment.UserName;
        public static string path = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.maycraft\Exist";
        public static string maypath = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.maycraft";
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            folderExist();
        }

        static void check1()
        {
            while (!Directory.Exists(maypath))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            
                existDownloading.Start();
        }

        static void folderExist()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(maypath))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\MayCraftLauncher.jar");
                check1();
            }
            else
            {
                fileExist();
            }
        }

        static void fileExist()
        {
            if (File.Exists(path)) //Determina se è la prima volta che l'applicazione viene eseguita
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exist");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                existDownloading.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading...");
            }
        }

        static void downloadExist()
        {
            WebClient Client = new WebClient();
            DateTime btime = DateTime.Now;
            path = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.maycraft\";
            string publicLinkExist = @"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35356155/minecraft/download/Exist";
            //string publicLinkMods = @"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35356155/minecraft/download/mods.7z";
            string publicLinkMods = @"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35356155/minecraft/download/mcp.7z";
            try
            {
                //----------------File downloading-------------------
                Client.DownloadFile(publicLinkExist, path);
                DirectoryInfo dev = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                string devpath = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\.maycraft";
                Client.DownloadFile(publicLinkMods, devpath);
                DateTime atime = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading time: " + atime.Subtract(btime).TotalSeconds + " sec.");

                //---------------Files Extracion-------------------
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(devpath))
                {
                    zip.ExtractAll(path);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\log.txt", e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            existDownloading.Abort();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's outputting to `\Roaming.maycraft`, which isn't "in" the `Roaming` folder but in the `AppData` root, where `\Roaming.maycraft` would be a file. Bottom line is this would be the same anywhere that you don't have the permissions to write.

Comment: As Grant said, you should create a folder where you can give permissions to ASP_NET process, and download the files from DropBox there. Alternatively, if you do not need to download and save the file, but just consume the contents on the fly, you can use Path.GetTempFileName to get a path to randomly generated file, and use StreamWriter to write into that file the contents of the dropbox file.